# No resultset returned where clause node js mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to search a mysql database by passing a token number and I want to return the id that is attached with that token from the database.
I have tried but I cant see any resultset and I am clueless as what am I doing wrong.
 This is what I tried so far.

```
checkifuniquenumberexists:function(num){
        con.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
            var post = {"token": num};
            var query = con.query('select id from uniquereviewtoken where token in (?)', post, function (err, result,fields) {
                // Neat!
             //console.log(query);
                console.log("error", err);
                console.log("result", result.length);
                console.log("fields",fields);
                return result;


            });

        });
```

Is there anything wrong with mysql syntax?

This is what I am getting in my logs

```
1|service  | undefined
1|service  | Connected!
1|service  | error null
1|service  | result 0
1|service  | fields [ FieldPacket {
1|service  |     catalog: 'def',
1|service  |     db: 'review',
1|service  |     table: 'uniquereviewtoken',
1|service  |     orgTable: 'uniquereviewtoken',
1|service  |     name: 'id',
1|service  |     orgName: 'id',
1|service  |     charsetNr: 63,
1|service  |     length: 50,
1|service  |     type: 3,
1|service  |     flags: 16899,
1|service  |     decimals: 0,
1|service  |     default: undefined,
1|service  |     zeroFill: false,
1|service  |     protocol41: true },
1|service  |   FieldPacket {
1|service  |     catalog: 'def',
1|service  |     db: 'review',
1|service  |     table: 'uniquereviewtoken',
1|service  |     orgTable: 'uniquereviewtoken',
1|service  |     name: 'token',
1|service  |     orgName: 'token',
1|service  |     charsetNr: 33,
1|service  |     length: 3000,
1|service  |     type: 253,
1|service  |     flags: 4097,
1|service  |     decimals: 0,
1|service  |     default: undefined,
1|service  |     zeroFill: false,
1|service  |     protocol41: true } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `post` object. 
Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries

```
checkifuniquenumberexists: function(num) {
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
        var query = con.query('select id from uniquereviewtoken where token in (?)', num, function(err, result, fields) {
            // Neat!
            //console.log(query);
            console.log("error", err);
            console.log("result", result.length);
            console.log("fields", fields);
            return result;


        });

    });
```